# Simplify mongodb query if (variable exists or not exists)

Tags: mongodb

I'm recieiving two or one of two variables from game client:
amount and amount2

I have code that setingcounters in mission in mongo DB, for both or for one of those variables:

```
if(amount && amount2) mMissionUser.update_task({id_user: id_user, id_mission: id_mission,     "tasks.id_task": id_task}, { $set: { "tasks.$.counter": amount, "tasks.$.counter2": amount2 } }, process);
else if(amount && !amount2) mMissionUser.update_task({id_user: id_user, id_mission: id_mission, "tasks.id_task": id_task}, { $set: { "tasks.$.counter": amount } }, process);
else if(!amount && amount2) mMissionUser.update_task({id_user: id_user, id_mission: id_mission, "tasks.id_task": id_task}, { $set: { "tasks.$.counter2": amount2 } }, process);
```

Do you know how to simplify it to do it in MONGODB query in one lane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build up your `$set` object programmatically and then apply it using a common `update` call:

```js
var set = {};
if (amount) set["tasks.$.counter"] = amount;
if (amount2) set["tasks.$.counter2"] = amount2;
mMissionUser.update_task(
    {id_user: id_user, id_mission: id_mission, "tasks.id_task": id_task}, 
    {$set: set}, 
    process);
```